# Gridview binding clears unexpectedly

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, gridview

I have a problem with my gridview. I have searched alot for the solution but can't find any answers. I think I have located the problem to be that the gridview is no longer bound when I press the update button - which results in null values. I thought it was enough to bind at RowEditing. Where else can I bind my gridview?

See the markup below:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="ProductGridView" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Id" OnRowEditing="ProductGridView_RowEditing"
    OnRowCancelingEdit="ProductGridView_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowUpdating="ProductGridView_RowUpdating"
    OnRowDeleting="ProductGridView_RowDeleting" OnDataBound="ProductGridView_DataBound" OnRowDataBound="ProductGridView_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" CausesValidation="false" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity" SortExpression="Quantity">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Quantity") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblQuantity" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Quantity") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Family" SortExpression="Family.Name">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFamily" runat="server" OnInit="ddlFamily_Init">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblFamily" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Family.Name") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And the code-behind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            BindGridView(_productRepo.GetAll());
        }
    }

    private void BindGridView(object source)
    {
        ProductGridView.DataSource = source;
        ProductGridView.DataBind();
    }

    protected void ProductGridView_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        ProductGridView.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        BindGridView(_productRepo.GetAll()); // GetAll returns an IEnumerable.
        rowCount = ProductGridView.Rows.Count; // Count is 6 here, which is correct.
    }

    protected void ProductGridView_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        rowCount = ProductGridView.Rows.Count; // Count is 0 here.
        //BindGridView(_productRepo.GetAll()); // Tried to rebind which works but getting the old values obviously. 
        //rowCount = ProductGridView.Rows.Count; // Count is 6 here.

        // Get the controls - all is null. Works ok when I use BindGridView above.
        TextBox txtName = FindChildControl<TextBox>(this.Page, "txtName");
        TextBox txtQuantity = FindChildControl<TextBox>(this.Page, "txtQuantity");
        DropDownList ddlFamily = FindChildControl<DropDownList>(this.Page, "ddlFamily");

        // More code to populate a new product and bind the gridview again etc.
    }
```

I also have a RowDataBound method. Can this contribute to the problem?

```
protected void ProductGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && (e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) == DataControlRowState.Edit)
        {
            DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlFamily");
            ddl.DataSource = _familyRepo.GetAll().Select(f => f.Name);
            ddl.DataBind();
            Product product = _productRepo.FindSingle(p => p.Id == (int)ProductGridView.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value);
            ddl.SelectedIndex = (int)product.FamilyID - 1;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are saying your form controls within your datagrid disappear or reset to their initial state after postback.

The reason this is happening is because you are binding your grid in the Page_Load method, which comes too late in the page lifecycle to restore the control values. Your grid doesn't load until AFTER the LoadViewstate and LoadPostbackData events are fired and therefore, your grid's controls are loaded with their original state every time a postback is made.

I'd guess you're familiar with the asp.net lifecycle, but if not here is an article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx. I've dealt with this issue many times, and it took me awhile to fully understand what was going on here.

One solution to the problem is to load the grid in the overridden OnInit method, which occurs before the control data is restored. Something like this should work:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);
    BindGridView(_productRepo.GetAll());
}
```

Comment: This was very helpful. The row count is the proper value now. However, my controls can't be found. Do you have any thoughts?

Comment: It looks like you are using a FindChildControl method that is looking at the entire page for controls with the given IDs. When finding a control within a GridView, you need to call "e.Row.FindControl(controlName)" like you did in your ProductGridView_RowDataBound.

Comment: I have also tried `TextBox txtName = (ProductGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtName") as TextBox);` without result. It returns null as well.

Comment: I have located the problem. When I step through the FindChildControl method it will only find labels. So, I think that when the update button is clicked the textboxes from the EditItemTemplates is returned to ItemTemplates before I have a chance to search through the gridview. I haven't found a solution to this yet.

Comment: I just tested out your code and was able to get a result from using TextBox txtName = (TextBox)ProductGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtName"); in the RowUpdating method. You should not be using the FindChildControl method with a gridview because each row has an index appended to the control's id. For example, the textbox of the first row's id is "ProductGridView_txtName_0". Only using the FindControl of the GridViewRow will get you the right object.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation about the FindChildControl! I have tried your code snippet and it is still null. This is so wierd..

Comment: I solved the problem by recreating the web form from scratch. Something was seriously wrong..

Answer (score 0):

I usually do data binding this way.... try this function and call it in your page load and other functions where you need it.

```
protected void bind()
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Your Query", con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;

    da.Fill(ds);

    gvCourse.DataSource = ds;
    gvCourse.DataBind();

    con.Close();

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, the code for the binding itself wasn't the problem. It was how and when to call the binding that I needed help with.

Comment: you should call your binding function whenever you make changes to your grid(like editing,updating and inserting) and if you want, in your page load too.you can call your binding function just like you call any other function, by its name.So in your program you should call the binding function at the end of your row editing function,row updating and page load.Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can simply replace the !Page.IsPostBack with !IsPostBack

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindGridView(_productRepo.GetAll());
    }
}
```